# Do Django backward relations add computational overhead?

Tags: python, django, model

In Django, you create models and can optionally specify a foreign key on a field

```
class Man:
      ...

class Dog:
      ...
      owner = models.ForeignKey(Man, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

You can then query each `Dog` for its respective owner or get all dogs for a `Man`

```
owner = some_dog.owner

all_dogs = some_man.dog_set.all()
```

If you want to not create a backward relation as specified by [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), you can do

```
class Man:
      ...

class Dog:
      ...
      owner = models.ForeignKey(Man, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')
```

Now you no longer have access to `all_dogs = some_man.dog_set.all()`.

However, does this additional "building" of a backward relation add overhead? If I just never ever used `all_dogs = some_man.dog_set.all()` would it matter whether or not I had specified `related_name='+'` in `Dog`? Would it slow things down potentially?

And is this functionality purely implemented in application side Django, or would `related_name='+'` also change the database schema itself? Thank you, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, does this additional "building" of a backward relation add overhead?

No

> If I just never ever used all_dogs = some_man.dog_set.all() would it matter whether or not I had specified related_name='+' in Dog? Would it slow things down potentially?

No, and no.

> And is this functionality purely implemented in application side Django, or would related_name='+' also change the database schema itself?

It's implemented with Python [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).  In the case of `ForeignKey`, that's a [`ReverseManyToOneDescriptor`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L468).
There is no change in the database schema, and the presence or absence of a related name does not generate a migration.

If you haven't disabled the relation, you should actually see the descriptor objects there as attributes on the model classes.  Something like this:

```
>>> Dog.owner
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor at 0x105db25d0>
>>> Man.dog_set
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ReverseManyToOneDescriptor at 0x105db27d0>
```

These are the objects which make Django's ORM magic work.